# javascript problem

Tags: javascript

I have created a dynamic table whose rows gets appended by click of the "Add" button, i want the user not to be able to submit the page if no value is entered in all the rows of the table.
how do i achieve this
The code is

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function addRowToTable()
 {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  var iteration = lastRow+1;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);
  var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('input');
  el.type = 'text';
  el.name = 'txtRow' + iteration;
  el.id = 'txtRow' + iteration;
  el.size = 40;
  cellRight.appendChild(el);  
 }
 function validation()
 {
                var a=document.getElementById('tblSample').rows.length;
                for(i=0;i<a;i++)
                {
   alert(document.getElementById('tblSample').txtRow[i].value);//this doesnt work
                }
  return true;
 }
 </script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form  name ='qqq' action="sample.html">
  <p>
   <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable();" />
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="return validation();" />
  </p>
  <p>
   <table border="1" id="tblSample">
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>The 1st row</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </p>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the validation to the onsubmit of the form:

..form onsubmit="return validate(this)"

2. loop over the form contents (assuming you added the inputs correctly)

```
  function validate(theForm) {
      var found = false;
      for(var i=0, n=theForm.elements.length; i < n;i++) {
      if (theForm.elements[i].name.indexOf('txtRow')==0 && theForm.elements[i].value!="") {
        found=true;
        break; // no need to hang around longer
      }
    }
    return found;
  }
```

Comment: its not working..its giving me the text of "Add" and "Submit" buttons..
Code is
function validation()
 {
  var found = false;
  for(var i=0, n=qqq.elements.length;i <n;i++)
  {
   alert(qqq.elements[i].value);
   if (qqq.elements[i].name.indexOf('txtRow')==0 && qqq.elements[i].value!="") 
   { 
    alert("not going inside this If condition");
    found=true;
     break; // no need to hang around longer 
   } 
  } 
  return found;
 }